# SIGABRT - Targeting Parse Push Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification, targeting

I am trying to save UISwitch results and using them to populate the "channels" for Parse.com push notifications. I followed the Parse Guide but I am getting a SIGABRT everytime I try and click the save button which saves the values of the switch. Any help is much appreciated

```
@IBAction func Save(sender: AnyObject) {

    if Athletics.on{
        let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        currentInstallation.addUniqueObject("Athletics", forKey: "channels")
        currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
    }else{let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        currentInstallation.removeObject("Athletics", forKey: "channels")
        currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
    }


    if Academics.on{
        let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        currentInstallation.addUniqueObject("Academics", forKey: "channels")
        currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
    }else{let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        currentInstallation.removeObject("Academics", forKey: "channels")
        currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
    }

    if LinkCrew.on{
        let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        currentInstallation.addUniqueObject("LinkCrew", forKey: "channels")
        currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
    }else{let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        currentInstallation.removeObject("LinkCrew", forKey: "channels")
        currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
    }

    if Events.on{
        let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        currentInstallation.addUniqueObject("Events", forKey: "channels")
        currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
    }else{let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        currentInstallation.removeObject("Events", forKey: "channels")
        currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
    }

    if Parents.on{
        let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        currentInstallation.addUniqueObject("Parents", forKey: "channels")
        currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
    }else{let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        currentInstallation.removeObject("Parents", forKey: "channels")
        currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
    }

    if Day1Day2.on{
        let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        currentInstallation.addUniqueObject("Day1Day2", forKey: "channels")
        currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
    }else{let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        currentInstallation.removeObject("Day1Day2", forKey: "channels")
        currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
    }


}
```

Comment: To identify which statement creates the error, set an exception breakpoint: In the breakpoint navigator of Xcode, click the plus sign down left and choose "Add exception breakpoints...", then hit return. Run your app, and it will stop at the problematic instruction.

Comment: Why not update all the channels then save once at the end...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with your code, it's with your main.storyboard. The SIGABRT error shows when a storyboard element is connected to some other element or outlet which does not exist anymore.

To fix this error:

1. Go to your main.storyboard
2. Click on one of your elements (e.g. UILabel, etc)
3. Click the connections inspector (looks like arrow in a circle)
4. See if it's connected to something that doesn't exist and delete it/them
5. Do steps 2 to 4 with all your elements